# How to use latex to achieve this effect, the number of subfig is shown in the figure

Tags: captions, subcaption, subfig

I want to achieve this kind of display effect, do you know how to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to clarify: By "this kind of display effect", are you referring to the numbering scheme I-a, I-b, II-a, and II-b, with the numbers surrounded by parentheses? Please advise.

Comment: yes Just use (I-a) as label

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

Observe that the subcaptions are placed quite closely below the respective images. This is a deliberate difference to the setup of the screenshot you provided, where the subcaptions are closer to the images directly below them.

I can't help but remark that not providing any information to the captions of the `subfigure` environments, and not providing any `figure`-level captions, can quickly become highly confusing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Roman{figure}}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure-\alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{} % to get form of cross-references right
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{pic1}
\caption{} \label{fig:aw}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{pic2}
\caption{} \label{fig:bx}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\refstepcounter{figure} % increment the 'figure' counter
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{pic3}
\caption{} \label{fig:cy}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{pic4}
\caption{} \label{fig:dz}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to subfigures \ref{fig:aw} and \ref{fig:dz}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much